# iOS Battery monitoring Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have set the monitoring enabled, but still the battery level is coming as -1 in both the simulator and on a physical device.

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryMonitoringEnabled = true
var level = UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel
```

The level variable is always -1 for the simulator and most of the time -1 for a physical device. What else should I do to get the value working?

Comment: What is the `batteryState`? It may be that it takes a few milliseconds to activate and you should listen to `UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification`.

Comment: batteryState rawValue is zero. Did that help? Tried to do UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification, but that is not getting invoked.

Comment: In the physical device it always prints the exact battery level. Are you sure that it is printing -1 on the device?

Comment: Hey @sivag1, where are you running this in your code? Are you doing it in viewDidLoad or somewhere else?

Comment: I tried to add the batteryMonitoringEnabled line in many places including the viewDidLoad. Also tried on the App delegate and made sure it is getting invoked.

Answer (score 6):

If battery monitoring is not enabled, battery state is `UIDevice.BatteryState.unknown` and the value of this property is –1.0. Ensure that you have enabled isBatteryMonitoringEnabled properly.

Swift 4

```
UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
let batteryLevel = UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems that batteryMonitoringEnabled doesn't work on Simulators.
It simply doesn't change when I set it to true. So state becomes UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown then.
Found no related notes in Apple's docs.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what's the problem but try this: 
Instead of using batterylevel, use

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState
```

Kindly provide your full code for apt answer.

Comment: How do I get the battery level then?

Comment: Please provide full code so that we may point out the mistake.