# UIDevice.batteryLevel always returns -1 in Simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, simulator

I was trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74224127/how-to-create-a-battery-badge-that-shows-current-battery-level-in-swiftui/74224558#74224558) question (the full code of the project is in that question) and I encountered an interesting problem, when I try to use `UIDevice.current.batteryLevel`, it always returns -1.0
**even though I set** `UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled` **to true**

in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620042-batterylevel), there's a definition that says it returns -1 if the battery monitoring is not enabled, but in my case it is enabled but it still returns -1

> Battery level ranges from 0.0 (fully discharged) to 1.0 (100% charged). Before accessing this property, ensure that battery monitoring is enabled.
>
> If battery monitoring is not enabled, battery state is UIDevice.BatteryState.unknown and the value of this property is –1.0.

Here's an example code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
        .onAppear {
            let batteryLevel = UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
            print(batteryLevel)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Battery monitoring Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991438/ios-battery-monitoring-swift)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991438/ios-battery-monitoring-swift is this helping ?

Comment: I don't think these questions contain any answers, also in that question the one who asked the question also says that it most of the time happens with physical devices too.

Comment: so I don't think these links are helpful @DavidAnsermot

Comment: Check the value of UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled after you set it to true. On the sim it's not supported - you'll see it remains false, as this answer says: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991438/ios-battery-monitoring-swift

Comment: @Shadowrun I also plugged my iphone 11 and it still returns false.

Comment: This isn't a valid question, downvoted.

Comment: This is a valid question, upvoted.